# Python multiprocessing get the results

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand the Python multiprocessing module. The below code creates 4 process and tries run the function `f(x)`.

Questions

1. I'm creating 4 processes but submitting multiple tasks (f,[10]). Will the module will automatically run every 4 process at any time?
2. I capture the result in a list. What will the `pool.apply_async` will return, Will it be print statements in the job or whatever returned by the method?

When I execute this code, it just displays 100 but not other values.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):

    print x*x
    return x*x


if __name__ == '__main__':

    result = []
    pool = Pool(processes=4)            
    result.append(pool.apply_async(f, [10]))
    out = map(lambda x: x.get(), result)
```

Comment: All of your questions are answered in the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pool you create has 4 processes available to it. You then give it a single job to do and it farms it out to one of its 4 workers. If you give it more jobs to do it will use more workers.

Comment: So, In my case..I have given 10 jobs...does it mean it will create 10 processes simultaneously or will it run 4 process and again create another 4 processess.

Comment: You define the number of workers available to the pool in your constructor. The pool has an internal queue and when you give it jobs via apply_async it puts these jobs on the queue. The worker processes then pick jobs off the queue (asynchronously). So if you give it 10 jobs then all 4 workers should be busy until the work queue is emptied...

Answer (score 1):

You're actually only submitting one task here: The function `f` with the argument tuple `(10,)`, meaning you're just executing `f(10)` in a single worker. If you had actually submitted more than 4 processes, the `Pool` would always execute at most 4 tasks simultaneously. As soon as one task finishes, a pending task will be started to replace it, until there are no remaining tasks. Also note that the same four processes will be used the entire time; they are not restarted after they complete a task, unless you supply the `maxtasksperchild` keyword argument when you create the `Pool`.

`apply_async` will return an [`AsyncResult`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) object, which can be used to fetch the result of the task, once it's available. You do that by calling `get()` on the `AsyncResult` object, so the `out` list will contain the return value of your one call to `f`. The stuff you `print` in the worker process will appear in stdout like it would if you ran it in the main process, but it doesn't get captured anywhere.